# git submodule folder is always case insensitive(lower case)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a folder called BuildTools, in the beginning it's under <parent_repo>\Build\ , later I set it as a submodule and still in same folder, but when I use tortoisegit to clone its parent repo and check "Recursive" to clone the submodule in whole cloning process, the folder is always lowercased "buildtools", aka <parent_repo>\Build\buildtools

The BuildTools repo is like below, you can see the root folder name beside "main" is "buildtools"

[image]

the .gitmodules file is like:

```
[submodule "BuildTools"]
    path = Build/buildtools
    url = ssh://<path>/buildtools.git
```

If I change the Build/buildtools to Build/BuildTools of course it doesn't work

Is there any way to keep the case?